# UseJava in CMake to GENERATE_NATIVE_HEADERS

Tags: java, cmake, java-native-interface

CMake seems to be really cool. Just the other day, I found out I can use it to compile Java sources into jars. There also is an option to [GENERATE_NATIVE_HEADERS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/UseJava.html). However, it just does not generate headers for me. The resulting Makefile invokes `javac` without `-h someplace`. Any hints what I might be missing? This is what I have so far:

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
find_package(Java 11 REQUIRED)
find_package(Java COMPONENTS Development)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)
add_jar(SomeJava 
    SomeJava.java
    ENTRY_POINT SomeJava
    GENERATE_NATIVE_HEADERS SomeJava-native
)
add_library(native SHARED
    native.c
)
target_include_directories(native PRIVATE
    ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

#### native.c

```
#include "SomeJava.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_SomeJava_printHelloWorld(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls) {
    printf("Native Hello World!\n");
}
```

#### SomeJava.java

```
public class SomeJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printHelloWorld();
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native");
    }
    public static native void printHelloWorld();
}
```

If I invoke `javac` manually to generate `SomeJava.h`, it works just fine.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: Also, what version of CMake?

Comment: @squareskittles CMake 3.10 and Java 11. I can upgrade to newer versions, if necessary.

Comment: see my updated answer, your CMake version is likely the issue.

Comment: @squareskittles I failed to realize the docs I was using for days were referring to a version different from the used one. Off by one minor version, though. I did not know CMake does not complain about unknown options. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the biggest pitfalls of using CMake. It will often show no errors or warnings for malformed commands or unsupported commands options, but instead will simply fail silently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the examples in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html#examples), it appears you may want to link to your produced `INTERFACE` target named `SomeJava-native`:

> The produced target for native headers can then be used to compile C/C++ sources with the target_link_libraries() command.

Currently, your code doesn't appear to use this target, so you can add this to the end of your CMake file:

```
target_link_libraries(native PRIVATE SomeJava-native)
```

---

Also, be sure your CMake version is 3.11 or greater, as the `GENERATE_NATIVE_HEADERS` feature was not available in earlier versions.